# Delete all Data using PHP (Delete all data/values in SQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help me, I am new here at PHP programming I want to know how to make a delete button that will Delete all data/values in the table on database [This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf4Bo.png)
[This is my button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34wDr.png)
[This is my delete code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SYSo.png) Wanted to get help from others this is my button code

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="Clear All Data's" style="float: right;">
</form> 
And this is my delete.php code <?php

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "qrcodedb";

$conn = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$dbname);

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  $name = $_POST['delete'];

  $query = "DELETE FROM table_attendance(NAME,TIMEIN) WHERE name='$name' ";
  $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  if($query_run)
  {
    echo '<script> alert("Data Deleted"); </script>';
    header("location:index.php");
  }
    else
  {
    echo '<script> alert("Data Not Deleted"); </script>';
    header("location:index.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: just `DELETE FROM table_attendance`; no WHERE, no column list

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the data from the table then you can use the **truncate** command.

The TRUNCATE TABLE command deletes the data inside a table, but not the table itself.

```
"TRUNCATE TABLE `table_attendance`"
```